# Is Gid Hanasheh issur hanaah

Tags: halacha, parts-of-the-body, yoreh-deah, issurei-hanaa, gid-hanashe

According to Halacha, is Gid Hanasheh considered issur hanaah, prohibited to benefit from, or merely prohibited to eat? Or is it similar to non kosher meat which is generally prohibited to make a business out of but may be sold occasionally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a dispute in the Talmud (Pesachim 22a) and Shulchan Arukh (YD 65:10) rules general benefit is permitted.